# parsing a log file have text between square brackets using spark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to use spark and python to parse log file stored in hdfs where the text and inside []

e.g. [abcd] [cdef] [...] [ .... ]

How can I use the below function for this purpose,

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="Log.py")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
 lines = sc.textFile("/user/abcd/abcd.log.................")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(" "))
```

Any pointers on how to use split function will be helpful.

---

**EDIT**

I applied the changes but its giving me the following error, any suggestions

```
IndexError: list index out of range
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:124)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:154)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:87)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:260)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:227)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Not sure what you did there. Can you post the new version of your code? What version of Spark are you using? Does every line in your file look like this: [abcd][cdef][...][ .... ] ?

Comment: I am new to spark world and still trying to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l[1:-1].split("]["))
```

Answer (score 0):

- The sample code is

  `sc = SparkContext(appName="SampleLogAnalysis.py")
  sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
  lines = sc.textFile("/user/root/abc.log.14")
  parts=lines.map(lambda l: l[1:-1].split("]["))
  people = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
  schemaString = "col1 col2"
  fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
  schema = StructType(fields)
  schemaPeople = sqlContext.applySchema(people, schema)
  schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people")
  results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people")
  names = results.map(lambda p: "Name: " + p.name)
  for name in names.collect():
  print name`
- Sample log file

[29 Dec 2014 12:42:46,354] [Thread-4] [DEBUG] [root] [taskname-1]Thread-4: reuse connection
[29 Dec 2014 12:42:46,362] [Thread-2] [DEBUG] [root] [tasknam-2]Thread-2: write remote call header...
[29 Dec 2014 12:42:46,353] [Thread-9] [DEBUG] [root] [taskname-1]Thread-9: write remote call header...
[29 Dec 2014 12:42:46,368] [Thread-2] [DEBUG] [root] [taskname-1Thread-2: getting output stream